# How do I export my Samsung Galaxy 551 contacts to my Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: contacts, sync

How do I export my Samsung Galaxy 551 contacts to my Samsung Galaxy S2?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without going via Google, just follow these steps. To make it easier for others to follow, I refer to your *Samsung Galaxy 551* as "old phone", and the *Samsung Galaxy S2* as "new phone":

1. On the old phone:

   1. Open the *Contacts* app
   2. Tap the "menu" button to bring up its extra menu
   3. Select "Export/Import", and chose to export your contacts to SDCard
   4. Pick the created file (it's most likely named `0001.vcf`, or at least similar – `.vcf` stands for "VCard File") and copy it to your PC
2. On the new phone:

   1. Copy the `0001.vcf` from your PC to the SDCard
   2. Follow steps 1-3 from above, but in step 3 this time chose to import the VCard File
   3. Select the VCard file from your SDCard, and have it imported

You're done – all contacts from your "old phone" should now be on the "new phone". Additionally, you've got a backup on your PC which you can easily import to other PC applications as well: most contact handling applications should understand this format.

Answer (score 0):

If your Samsung Galaxy 551 is already synced to Google and you have enabled syncing for Google contacts, then all you need to do is use your Google account on the Samsung Galaxy S2. Once the S2 syncs, it will pick up the contacts that you synced using the Samsung Galaxy 551.